# How to change a value from an XML file using Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an *integers.xml* located at **res/values**. What I want to achieve is to change a value (an int) to some other int, by using Java. This is my code and as you can see I am using the Random class to assign it to the xml *Degree* value. But it doesn't work...

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random objRandom = new Random();
            int intRandomNumber  = objRandom.nextInt(1440 - 1080 + 1) + 1080;
            int intXMLDegree = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.Degree);
            intXMLDegree = intRandomNumber;

            iv.startAnimation(rotation);


        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, you never write the changed value out/save it anywhere other than the intXMLDegree local value. Does Android Studio not give you a warning about "Assigned value never used"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change and why do you want to change. The values you specify in XML file is mapped to a final variable in R.java file.

If you want to perist data , then try out shared preferences in Android

Comment: Because I want to have a different value in the XML file, everytime I press a button.

Comment: No, XML files are not supposed to do that. If you want t tk

Comment: If you want to persist data, check out shared preferences in Android

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info! You can post your comment as an answer so I can Mark it as solved.

Comment: Thanks , Done . appreciate that